# Chrome adds header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have an (enforced) CSP policy containing, among other directives, `worker-src` and `report-uri`.

For some reason, when loading the site with Chrome (80.0.3987.122), the Network tab also shows the header `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: worker-src 'none'; report-uri about:blank`.

This conflicts with the settings in my `Content-Security-Policy` header, blocking the service worker from being loaded (and logging an error to console regarding the invalid `report-uri`).

When I load the same site with Firefox, I do not see this mysterious additional header.

Does anyone experience something similar? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it’s not actually being added by browser extension? You’ve tested with extensions disabled?

Comment: @sideshowbarker You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the CSP Injection feature of [uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix), more details can be found [here](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki/Raw-settings#disablecspreportinjection).

Note that this setting has to be set to true to disable the additional `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header.